# How to convert from the "integer" to the "double" object type while retaining columns in R?

Tags: r, type-conversion, integer, double

I want my data to be the "double" rather than the "integer" object category to be able to work with a specific R package, while retaining the separation of the data into distinct columns designating different sites. I have tried using the as.double() function, but this creates a string of numbers which are not separated into the columns which they have previously. Is there a way to convert to doubles to be able to work with this R package while retaining the categorisation of the data in its currents rows & columns?

To give you an example of the data I am trying to convert, and what I am trying to convert it to, here is one of the integers I have in my data:

```
structure(c(97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 102L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dim = c(6L, 3L), dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("det.covs.day.day141", "det.covs.day.day142", "det.covs.day.day143"
    )))
```

Here is a subset of that data:

```
      det.covs.day.day141 det.covs.day.day142 det.covs.day.day143
 [1,]                  97                  NA                  NA
 [2,]                  97                  NA                  NA
 [3,]                  98                  NA                  NA
 [4,]                  98                  NA                  NA
 [5,]                  98                  NA                  NA
 [6,]                 102                  NA                  NA
 [7,]                 103                  NA                  NA
 [8,]                 103                  NA                  NA
 [9,]                 108                  NA                  NA
[10,]                 124                  NA                  NA
[11,]                 126                 127                 128
[12,]                 136                 137                 138
[13,]                 148                 148                 149
[14,]                 188                  NA                  NA
[15,]                 204                 210                  NA
[16,]                 204                 210                  NA
[17,]                 204                 210                  NA
[18,]                 204                 210                  NA
[19,]                 204                 210                  NA
[20,]                 204                 210                  NA
[21,]                 204                 210                  NA
[22,]                 204                 210                  NA
[23,]                 204                 210                  NA
[24,]                 204                 210                  NA
[25,]                 204                 210                  NA
[26,]                 204                 210                  NA
[27,]                 204                 210                  NA
[28,]                 204                 210                  NA
[29,]                 204                 210                  NA
[30,]                 205                  NA                  NA
```

And here is the equivalent part of data in the tutorial for the R package:

```
structure(c(156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 156, 167, 167, 167, 167, 
167, 167, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187), dim = c(6L, 3L))
```

And here is a subset of the data used in the tutorial:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]  156  167  187
  [2,]  156  167  187
  [3,]  156  167  187
  [4,]  156  167  187
  [5,]  156  167  187
  [6,]  156  167  187
  [7,]  156  167  180
  [8,]  156  167  180
  [9,]  156  167  180
 [10,]  156  167  180
 [11,]  156  167  180
 [12,]  156  167  180
 [13,]  156  167  180
 [14,]  156  167  180
 [15,]  156  167  180
 [16,]  156  167  181
 [17,]  156  167  181
 [18,]  156  167  181
 [19,]  156  167  180
 [20,]  156  167  180
 [21,]  156  167  180
 [22,]  156  167  180
 [23,]  156  167  180
 [24,]  156  167  180
 [25,]  156  167  180
 [26,]  156  167  180
 [27,]  156  167  187
 [28,]  156  167  187
 [29,]  156  167  187
 [30,]  156  167  187
```

In case it helps, the R package in question is spOccupancy https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spOccupancy/index.html

Comment: Show a sample of your data here so people can help. try `dput(head(data))`

Answer (score 1):

R is a little confusing when it comes to storage modes of numerics. `"numeric"` and `"double"` are often used interchangeably, and `as.numeric()`/`as.double()` are entirely identical. Strictly speaking, `"numeric"` is a 'mode', and `"double"` is a 'type'. Both types `"double"` and `"integer"` are mode `"numeric"`, while type `"integer"` is also mode `"integer"`. `is.numeric()` and `is.double()` are not equivalent, as the former casts a wider net.

Here are all the ways I could think of for converting an integer matrix to a numeric one.

```
if (!require("Hmisc")) llist <- list

m <- matrix(as.integer(0:99), 10)[1:4, 1:4]
typeof(m); mode(m)
# [1] "integer"
# [1] "numeric"

l <- list(

    original=m,
    apply(m, 2, as.numeric),
        
    "storage.mode<-"(m, "numeric"),
    # in-line version of:
    # storage.mode(m) <- "numeric"

    "mode<-"(m, "numeric"),
    # in-line version of:
    # mode(m) <- "numeric"
    
    "[<-"(m, as.numeric(m)),
    # in-line version of:
    # m[] <- as.numeric(m)
    
    "dim<-"(as.numeric(m), dim(m))
    # in-line equivalent of:
    # dm <- dim(m)
    # m <- as.numeric(m)
    # dim(m) <- dm
)

str(l)
# List of 6
#  $ original: int [1:4, 1:4] 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 ...
#  $         : num [1:4, 1:4] 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 ...
#  $         : num [1:4, 1:4] 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 ...
#  $         : num [1:4, 1:4] 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 ...
#  $         : num [1:4, 1:4] 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 ...
#  $         : num [1:4, 1:4] 0 1 2 3 10 11 12 13 20 21 ...
sapply(l, function(x) {
    llist(typeof(x), storage.mode(x), mode(x), is.numeric(x), is.double(x))
})
#                 original                                        
# typeof(x)       integer  double  double  double  double  double 
# storage.mode(x) integer  double  double  double  double  double 
# mode(x)         numeric  numeric numeric numeric numeric numeric
# is.numeric(x)   TRUE     TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE   
# is.double(x)    FALSE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

The two functions `as.double()` and `as.numeric()` are identical and they both convert a matrix into a vector, as you have noticed.

The way to go is to use `apply()` to apply the function `as.numeric()` (or `as.double()`, if you prefer) to each column of the matrix as follows:

```
m <- structure(c(97L, 97L, 98L, 98L, 98L, 102L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dim = c(6L, 3L), dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("det.covs.day.day141", "det.covs.day.day142", "det.covs.day.day143"
  )))
m_num <- apply(m, 2, as.numeric)
m_num
##      det.covs.day.day141 det.covs.day.day142 det.covs.day.day143
## [1,]                  97                  NA                  NA
## [2,]                  97                  NA                  NA
## [3,]                  98                  NA                  NA
## [4,]                  98                  NA                  NA
## [5,]                  98                  NA                  NA
## [6,]                 102                  NA                  NA
```

As you can see, the shape of the matrix and the column names are kept intact. The new matrix is no longer an integer:

```
is.integer(m_num)
## [1] FALSE
```

It is important to note, that integers are also numeric:

```
is.numeric(m)
## [1] TRUE
is.numeric(m_num)
## [1] TRUE
```

So, you can not use `is.numeric()` to distinguish between integers and doubles, but `is.double()` can do the job:

```
is.double(m)
## [1] FALSE
is.double(m_num)
## [1] TRUE
```

Somewhat confusingly, floating point numbers are nevertheless called "numeric" in R:

```
class(2.5)
## [1] "numeric"
```